# Visual Studio C# process.WaitForExit(); Causing Launcher UI To Freeze

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have made a specific launcher in VS that launches an exe / cmd with args, but when a user presses the button that does this the launcher UI totally freezes up until the exe / cmd is closed. I know it's process.WaitForExit(); that's causing the issue but I wondered if anyone had a fix for my shambles of a code. Thanks.

```
    public static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
    {
        Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        });
        process.WaitForExit();
        string end1 = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string end2 = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        Console.WriteLine("output>>" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(end1) ? "(none)" : end1));
        Console.WriteLine("error>>" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(end2) ? "(none)" : end2));
        Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), (object)nameof(ExecuteCommand));
        process.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UI freezes because `process.WaitForExit();` is a blocking call. In case you want UI to not freeze you have to use `process.Exited` event.

Code below might do what you need to achieve.

```cs
public static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
    Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command)
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    });

    process.Exited += new EventHandler(Process_Exited);
}

private void Process_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

{
    var process = (Process)sender;
    string end1 = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string end2 = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    int exitCode = process.ExitCode;
    Console.WriteLine("output>>" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(end1) ? "(none)" : end1));
    Console.WriteLine("error>>" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(end2) ? "(none)" : end2));
    Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), (object)nameof(ExecuteCommand));
    process.Close();
}
```

There is an example directly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=net-8.0#examples). I would take inspiration from there in case you run into additional issues.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issue as I get swamped with errors, but it has given me some information.

Comment: What errors it gave you?

Comment: Around 60 errors. It seems to be conflicting with something or another. I just can't work it out.

Comment: Can you share more code in your question? It is hard to work it out without more to work with.

Comment: Well wouldnt a problem arise from the fact that once the process is established and the event is attached we leave the method in which the process exists? Like one the Method is finished its just gonna "clean out" the data of its variables. I could be wrong though since I dont really work with processes, but Im just projecting general coding knowledge on thbis issue.

Comment: You might be right. There is documentation and example how to use it (properly). Everything is down to how is it used in @Lee ‘s solution as there is very little code shared in the question.

Comment: Id also say that it would be usefull to see some of the errors that they seem to get.